# Cleaning up cut and pasted outlook email addresses

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I often have to create or update e-mail distribution lists in SSMS, where the requestor will ask "please add Anne Hathaway, Albert Einstein, and Ash Ketchum to the DL.  Get their email from Outlook."

Once I put their names in outlook and push the "Check Names" function, it validates they're still in the system.  Copying this list then produces the following output.

```
Anne Hathaway < Anne.Hathaway@Email.com >; Albert Einstein < Albert.Einstein@email.com >; Ash Ketchum < Ash.Ketchum@mail.com >
```

It's a manual process to remove the original name and < > signs, which of course could open itself to error.

How can I set a variable that, when I paste in the raw data straight from outlook ,it cleans it up so that it gets rid of everything left of the < up to but not including the next encountered ; ?

I'd like the variable to print like so. 
'Anne.Hathaway@email.com; Albert.Einstein@email.com; Ash.Ketchum@mail.com'

Comment: So are you storing these addresses in a table somewhere? What's that table look like?

Comment: I know this doesn't solve it, but this is one of those occasions where I'd simply start requesting the emails in the format I need them instead of needing to create/maintain a piece of code. This also ensures you're getting the right addresses and there is no manual mistakes from common/duplicate names, etc. Otherwise, [try this](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/outlook/129213/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a recursive common table expression to iterate through the string variable:

```
DECLARE @outlook nvarchar(max)='Something.something@email.com;Anne Hathaway < Anne.Hathaway@Email.com >; Albert Einstein < Albert.Einstein@email.com >; Ash Ketchum < Ash.Ketchum@mail.com >';

WITH semi AS (
    SELECT CAST(NULL AS nvarchar(255)) AS part, @outlook AS remain
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(LEFT(remain, CHARINDEX(';', remain+';')-1) AS nvarchar(255)),
           CAST(SUBSTRING(remain, CHARINDEX(';', remain+';')+1, LEN(remain)) AS nvarchar(max))
    FROM semi
    WHERE remain!='')

SELECT +LEFT(addr, CHARINDEX('>', addr+'>')-1)
FROM (
    SELECT LTRIM(SUBSTRING(part, CHARINDEX('<', part)+1, LEN(part))) AS addr
    FROM semi
    WHERE part IS NOT NULL
    ) AS sub;
```

Ok, so what's going on here is that the "semi" common table expression splits the string using the semicolon character (and if one of your names has a semicolon in it, you're out of luck).

Once we've split every name/address into its own row, the bottom `SELECT` gets only the string between the `<` and `>` characters.

If you want to go a little crazy with it, you could use XML parsing to concatenate all those lines back on a single row:

```
WITH semi AS (
    SELECT CAST(NULL AS nvarchar(255)) AS part, @outlook AS remain
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(LEFT(remain, CHARINDEX(';', remain+';')-1) AS nvarchar(255)),
           CAST(SUBSTRING(remain, CHARINDEX(';', remain+';')+1, LEN(remain)) AS nvarchar(max))
    FROM semi
    WHERE remain!='')

SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST((
    SELECT '; '+LEFT(addr, CHARINDEX('>', addr+'>')-1)
    FROM (
        SELECT LTRIM(SUBSTRING(part, CHARINDEX('<', part)+1, LEN(part))) AS addr
        FROM semi
        WHERE part IS NOT NULL
        ) AS sub
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS nvarchar(max)), 3, 10000);
```

To round off the answer, if you have access to a SQL Server 2017 instance, this is just a few lines of code:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(b.[value], '<', ''), '>', ''))), '; ')
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@outlook, ';') AS a
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(a.[value], ' ') AS b
WHERE b.[value] LIKE '%@%';
```

Comment: This is perfect! I really like that you added the xml parsing to concatenate the addresses into a single row, and especially like that you took the time to explain what each CTE is doing. Thank you very much!